# Label shapefile by attribute in Google Earth Engine

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine, labeling, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have imported a shapefile of points into Google Earth Engine but am unable to find information on how to label them by their assigned number in the attribute table. I saw a related thread but the code provided was not successful. This is what I have tried:

```
// Step 7) Add GRTs points to map
var styling = {color: 'orange', fillColor: '00000000'};
Map.addLayer(HCSR_MgmtGRTs.style(styling), HCSR_MgmtGRTs, "HCSR GRTS");

// Step 8) Label points
var text = require('users/gena/packages:text')
// scale text font relative to the current map scale
var scale = Map.getScale() * 1

var labels = HCSR_MgmtGRTs.map(function(feat) {
  feat = ee.Feature(feat)
  var number = ee.String(feat.get("NUMBER"))
  var centroid = feat.geometry().centroid()
  var t = text.draw(number, centroid, scale, {
    fontSize:18, 
    textColor:'orange',
    outlineWidth: 1,
    outlineColor: 'orange'
  })
  return t
})

labels = ee.ImageCollection(labels)
Map.addLayer(labels)
```

It runs without error, but I am not seeing any labels on my points. I am a beginner, so an easy explanation would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this (probably following same youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmaaEFbBtfQ) for my point shapefile and it worked:

````
var text = require('users/gena/packages:text')
var scale = Map.getScale() * 1 // You can reduce 1 to 0.25 or even less if labels too big like it was for me
var shp = ee.FeatureCollection(Vegetation_points) //Vegetation_points is my shapefile that I had imported in GEE before

var labels = shp.map(function(feat) {
  feat = ee.Feature(feat)
  var name = ee.String(feat.get("Name")) //"Name" is the name of the column of the table of attribute of my shapefile containing the labels.
  var centroid = feat.geometry().centroid()
  var t = text.draw(name, centroid, scale, {
    fontSize:12, //looks like you cannot chose another size than 12 (but it can be scaled anyway using the var scale above
    textColor:'black',
    outlineWidth: 0.5,
    outlineColor:'black'
  })
  return t
})

var labels_final = ee.ImageCollection(labels)
Map.addLayer(labels_final, {}, "Vegetation_points_labels")```
````